# Questa instantiation during testbench issues

Tags: clock-speed, testbench, eda, questasim

I'm new to EDA and trying to get the hang of simulations in Questa. I wrote the Verilog code "clock_divider" and the testbench "tb_clock_divider". They both compile successfully and are in the same path. So, why when I start the simulation on the testbench does the clock_divider instantiation not appear underneath the testbench as a U1 layer?

[image: verilog modules]

[image: simulation on tb_clock_divider, no addition of the clock_divider instantiation]

[image: testbench]

[image: verilog code I want to stimulate]